# Ember-CLI - Error running default application

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Trying to run a simple, empty Ember-CLI based application, but it's generating an error in the console:

> Could not find "index" template or view. Nothing will be rendered 
>   Object

Trying to wrap my head around Ember and Ember-CLI, but I don't even know where to start!

The full log of from the console is:

```
[Log] [ ] router:main ................................................ simple/main/router (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [✓] router:main ................................................ simple/router (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [✓] router:main ................................................ simple/router (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] application:main ........................................... simple/main/application (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] application:main ........................................... simple/application (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] application:main ........................................... simple/applications/main (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Debug] DEBUG: ------------------------------- (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Debug] DEBUG: Ember      : 1.5.1 (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Debug] DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.8.2a68c63a (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Debug] DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0 (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Debug] DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.1 (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Debug] DEBUG: ------------------------------- (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] store:application .......................................... simple/application/store (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] store:application .......................................... undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] store:application .......................................... simple/stores/application (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] store:main ................................................. simple/main/store (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] store:main ................................................. simple/store (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] store:main ................................................. simple/stores/main (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] event_dispatcher:main ...................................... simple/main/event_dispatcher (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] event_dispatcher:main ...................................... simple/event_dispatcher (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] event_dispatcher:main ...................................... simple/event_dispatchers/main (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] router:main ................................................ simple/main/router (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [✓] router:main ................................................ simple/router (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [✓] router:main ................................................ simple/router (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] -location-setting:root-url ................................. simple/root-url/-location-setting (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] -location-setting:root-url ................................. undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] -location-setting:root-url ................................. simple/-location-settings/root-url (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] location:auto .............................................. simple/auto/location (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] location:auto .............................................. undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] location:auto .............................................. simple/locations/auto (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] -location-setting:root-url ................................. simple/root-url/-location-setting (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] -location-setting:root-url ................................. undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] -location-setting:root-url ................................. simple/-location-settings/root-url (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] route:basic ................................................ simple/basic/route (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] route:basic ................................................ undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] route:basic ................................................ simple/routes/basic (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] route:basic ................................................ simple/basic/route (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] route:basic ................................................ undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] route:basic ................................................ simple/routes/basic (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] route:application .......................................... simple/application/route (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] route:application .......................................... undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] route:application .......................................... simple/routes/application (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] route:application .......................................... simple/application/route (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] route:application .......................................... undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] route:application .......................................... simple/routes/application (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] route:application .......................................... simple/application/route (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] route:application .......................................... undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] route:application .......................................... simple/routes/application (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] route:application .......................................... simple/application/route (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] route:application .......................................... undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] route:application .......................................... simple/routes/application (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] generated -> route:application  (vendor.js, line 16672)
Object

[Log] [ ] route:index ................................................ simple/index/route (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] route:index ................................................ undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] route:index ................................................ simple/routes/index (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] route:index ................................................ simple/index/route (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] route:index ................................................ undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] route:index ................................................ simple/routes/index (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] route:index ................................................ simple/index/route (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] route:index ................................................ undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] route:index ................................................ simple/routes/index (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] route:index ................................................ simple/index/route (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] route:index ................................................ undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] route:index ................................................ simple/routes/index (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] generated -> route:index  (vendor.js, line 16672)
Object

[Log] [ ] controller:application ..................................... simple/application/controller (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] controller:application ..................................... undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] controller:application ..................................... simple/controllers/application (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] controller:application ..................................... simple/application/controller (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] controller:application ..................................... undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] controller:application ..................................... simple/controllers/application (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] controller:basic ........................................... simple/basic/controller (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] controller:basic ........................................... undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] controller:basic ........................................... simple/controllers/basic (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] controller:basic ........................................... simple/basic/controller (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] controller:basic ........................................... undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] controller:basic ........................................... simple/controllers/basic (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] controller:application ..................................... simple/application/controller (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] controller:application ..................................... undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] controller:application ..................................... simple/controllers/application (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] controller:application ..................................... simple/application/controller (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] controller:application ..................................... undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] controller:application ..................................... simple/controllers/application (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] generated -> controller:application  (vendor.js, line 16672)
Object

[Log] [ ] view:application ........................................... simple/application/view (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] view:application ........................................... undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] view:application ........................................... simple/views/application (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] view:application ........................................... simple/application/view (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] view:application ........................................... undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] view:application ........................................... simple/views/application (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] template:application ....................................... simple/application/template (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] template:application ....................................... simple/templates/application (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [✓] template:application ....................................... simple/templates/application (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [✓] template:application ....................................... simple/templates/application (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] view:toplevel .............................................. simple/toplevel/view (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] view:toplevel .............................................. undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] view:toplevel .............................................. simple/views/toplevel (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] view:toplevel .............................................. simple/toplevel/view (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] view:toplevel .............................................. undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] view:toplevel .............................................. simple/views/toplevel (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] Rendering application with default view <simple@view:toplevel::ember277>  (vendor.js, line 16672)
Object

[Log] [ ] controller:index ........................................... simple/index/controller (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] controller:index ........................................... undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] controller:index ........................................... simple/controllers/index (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] controller:index ........................................... simple/index/controller (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] controller:index ........................................... undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] controller:index ........................................... simple/controllers/index (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] controller:index ........................................... simple/index/controller (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] controller:index ........................................... undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] controller:index ........................................... simple/controllers/index (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] controller:index ........................................... simple/index/controller (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] controller:index ........................................... undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] controller:index ........................................... simple/controllers/index (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] generated -> controller:index  (vendor.js, line 16672)
Object

[Log] [ ] view:index ................................................. simple/index/view (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] view:index ................................................. undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] view:index ................................................. simple/views/index (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] view:index ................................................. simple/index/view (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] view:index ................................................. undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] view:index ................................................. simple/views/index (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] template:index ............................................. simple/index/template (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] template:index ............................................. undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] template:index ............................................. simple/templates/index (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] template:index ............................................. simple/index/template (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] template:index ............................................. undefined (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] [ ] template:index ............................................. simple/templates/index (vendor.js, line 16672)
[Log] Could not find "index" template or view. Nothing will be rendered  (vendor.js, line 16672)
Object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't an error, it's just an informational log: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-application/lib/system/resolver.js#L368-L380

Ember is telling you what objects it went looking for and which objects it found. Not all objects are required to be implemented, depending on what effect you're trying to get.